# How to use a variable from another class

Tags: static-variables

I have a class Overview where i try to save a Customer.
Now i want to use that Customer in another class. Now i'm using Public Static value, but my teacher said it's not good to use static variables. Can you solve this

```
public class OverView {
  public static Customer CurrentCustomer;

  CurrentCustomer = new Customer("Tom",23);
}

public class removeCustomer{

  Customer removeCustomer = OverView.CurrentCustomer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is right, do not interface with static variables directly, implement getter/setter methods

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method for more information!

Comment: ok then in addition to using get and set methods in THE OverView class, make a new variable to OverView in the removeCustomer class e.g. var and do `Customer removeCustomer = var.CurrentCustomer`

Comment: Erm combine my answer with the other guy's anwser

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of Overview to access its non-static members.  Try:

```
public class OverView {
  public Customer CurrentCustomer = new Customer("Tom",23);
}

Public class removeCustomer{

  OverView ov = new OverView();
  Customer removeCustomer = ov.CurrentCustomer;
}
```

It is also adviseable to not declare the CurrentCustomer as public, and implement public get/set methods to access it

Comment: No it doesn't work i try to do this but i get an error by Overview ov = new Overview(); Unhandled exception type RepositoryException

Comment: I assume there is at least one Overview object created.  You need to pass that instance to the removeCusomer class (via its constructor) and store it in a member variable (e.g. `ov` in my answer), then use that instead of creating a new one

Comment: I cannot put it in code because I do not have enough context.  The code you presented allows me to deduce as much as I wrote in the answer, but since creating an Overview object on the fly is not an option, I do not know how one is actually created.  Based on your comments, you clearly have trouble understanding the fundamental ideas of the language.  I suggest you make an appointment with your teacher or a tutor at your school to have the basics explained.

Answer (score 0):

Even better: in your example, you don't need to touch the instance of Customer at all.  The "remove" functionality should be a member method on the Customer class.  I'm not even sure that you need currentCustomer to be static, but I kept it static.

```
public class Customer {

    //Customer constructor, etc.

    * * * 

    public void remove() {
        //remove the customer, whatever that entails
    }

}

public class OverView {

    private static Customer currentCustomer;

    public static void someMethod() {
        currentCustomer = new Customer("Tom",23);

        * * *

        //all done with this customer
        currentCustomer.remove();

        //but notice that the currentCustomer object still exists
    }
}
```